# Creating a jquery element from two other elements (code explanation request)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if someone could explain the following lines to me:

```
var panel = parseInt($el.parent().attr('data-panel'));
var $curr_panel = $('.h5p-panel:eq(' + panel + ')', that.$myDom);
var $next_panel = $('.h5p-panel:eq(' + (panel + 1) + ')', that.$myDom);
```

If someone could walk me through it in simple english I would really appreciate it.

I understand that $curr_panel and $next_panel are created by the combination of an element in h5p panel and a dom element, but thereafter I'm a quite confused.

The code can be found here:

https://github.com/h5p/h5p-summary/blob/master/js/summary.js#L222

And a live demo here:

https://h5p.org/summary

Comment: What dont you understand ? the variable panel is a panel index in data-panel attribut (that is a jquery data) from what the code gets the selected panel and the next one, because eq() is using index to select a DOM element.
In fact, there is a minor mistake, this should be $el.parent().data('panel') instead of $el.parent().attr('data-panel') but the result is the same.

Comment: I was confused about the setting of the context in the second line but @Abdennour TOUMI cleared it up. Thanks for catching the error, could I ask why it is considered an error?

Comment: If i understand, $("selector", parent) is the same than $(parent).find("selector")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand before :

1. `that` => refres to an instance of  `Summary` class.

   ```
   119   Summary.prototype.createQuestion = function() {
   120        var that = this;
   ```
2. `that.$myDom` => jQuery element `<div class="summary-content"/>`

   ```
    124 this.$myDom = $('<div>', {
    125       'class': 'summary-content'
    126   });
   ```
3. `$(A,B)` => means select `A` where `B` is one of its parents (context). 
         [same `B.find(A)`]
4. `$('.CLASS:eq(i)',B)` => means select the (i+1) element has Css class `CLASS` & one of its parents is `B`.

## Conclusion :

```
$curr_panel = $('.h5p-panel:eq(' + panel + ')', that.$myDom);
```

Means, select DOM element where :

- has Css class= `h5p-panel`
- the 3rd element , if we assume `panel=2` . (because `eq(0)` => 1st element)
- one of its parents is `that.$myDom`